# Compliation Error While referencing iTextSharp Dll in mono for android

Tags: android, mono, xamarin.android, monodevelop

I get the following error while referencing the iTextSharp dll

> C:\Program Files\MSBuild\Novell\Novell.MonoDroid.Common.targets(2,2):
>   Error: Exception while loading assemblies:
>   System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load assembly
>   'System.Drawing, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. Perhaps it doesn't exist in the Mono
>   for Android profile?
>
> File name: 'System.Drawing.dll'
>
> at Monodroid.Tuner.MonoDroidResolver.Resolve(AssemblyNameReference
>   reference, ReaderParameters parameters)
>
> at
>   Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.AddAssemblyReferences(List`1
>   assemblies, AssemblyDefinition assembly)
>
> at Xamarin.Android.Tasks.ResolveAssemblies.Execute() (Dashmate)

Also I tried to add System.Drawing.dll , but it still did not resolve the
error.

Guess the System.Drawing within the Mono.Android.dll is conflicting with the
System.Drawing.dll which is being referenced by the iTextSharp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got this reply from the Development team of Xamarin

> You cannot use System.Drawing.dll which is available only in full .NET
>   profile. Mono for Android supports only its mobile-based profile which
>   is almost the same as Silverlight

So, I guess that we could not use Third Party dll's which has the **"System.Drawing" Class** :(

Answer (score 2):

The error is telling you that the (managed) linker is not able to load an assembly. This assembly is needed to satisfy some references required by the code you're linking. Without it the linker is not able to rewrite a smaller valid (i.e. working) assembly.

In this case it looks like `iTextSharp` compiled against *desktop* framework assemblies (i.e. the 2.0.0.0 version is the hint, Mono for Android versions would be 2.1.x).

In general the solution to such problems is to recompile the project (iTextSharp in this case) against the assemblies that Mono for Android provides. That way all references will be against M4A assemblies and the linker will be able to process them (since nothing will be missing from them, otherwise it would fail at compile time).

Note that it might not be possible to re-compile, from source, iTextSharp if it depends on too many things from `System.Drawing.dll`.

> Also I tried to add System.Drawing.dll , but it still did not resolve the error.

Using *desktop* assemblies is unlikely to work (as they depend on different assemblies, with different types...).

Furthermore the `System.Drawing.dll` shipped with Windows (or Mono) would not work with Mono for Android since they depend on GDI+ (or libgdiplus for Mono) which is not part of Android.

> Guess the System.Drawing within the Mono.Android.dll is conflicting with the System.Drawing.dll which is being referenced by the iTextSharp

There is no assembly conflict since Mono for Android does **not** ship with a `System.Drawing.dll` assembly. However some types (e.g. `Rectangle[F]`, `Point[F]` and `Size[F]`) are included (in another assembly) that uses the `System.Drawing.*` namespaces since they are helpful (and well known) to .NET developers.

Comment: Hi, I have tried to use different libraries that referenced only the **System.Drawing.dll**, including a custom library of my own, But the same issue remains.
Also, I tried to use the **System.Drawing.dll** in the application it showed **_Anonymous Class Color_** as the class Color was declared both in System.Drawing.dll and Mono.Android.dll's System.Drawing Namespace, 
So this might have made the issue while referencing the other dlls, When I try to use a dll that doesn't have **Drawing.dll** It works fine :(